# Several flot graphs not working in IE8

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, flot

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs for showing several graphs, using Flot. This works perfectly fine in every browser but IE8. It looks like IE8 doesn't support several Flot graphs next to each other.
Anyone experienced this before?

I'm rendering the graphs when the specific tab is selected, see code below.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var tab = ui.index+1;
        if(tab == 1)
            rendergraph1();
        else if(tab == 2)
            rendergraph2();
        else if(tab == 3)
            rendergraph3();
    }
});
```

The renderGraph1/2 functions just render the graphs with some options, like this:

```
function rendergraph1()
{
    $.plot($("#graph1"), data, {
    .....
```

Again, the code is working fine in Firefox. This is why I won't bother you with the full rendergraph code :)
Anyone experienced this before?

Comment: When you say that it doesn't support several graphs next to each other, do you mean that it works with a single plot?

Comment: And are you properly including Excanvas?

Comment: @DNS No, I have a rendergraph function for every graph. This function contains a $.plot, a plot for every graph (is that what you mean?). And the first graph is shown fine, only the graphs in the other tabs don't work properly. The axis and legenda's are shown but the graph lines are invisible. I guess Excanvas is included properly then..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your other tabs are hidden until after you draw the plot.  There are several issues with hidden divs under older versions of IE.

Try showing the tab/div before you call plot, rather than after.  If you have other stuff to do, or are using some kind of transition, you can always hide the tab/div immediately afterwards and then show it later; it just needs to be visible and attached to the DOM when you call plot.

Comment: I now use the select event of the tabs. I guess the div is still invisible in that event. Maybe there is an event that is fired after the div is shown. I'll try it at work tomorrow, and let you know!

Comment: I changed the 'select' event of the tab to the show event. Probably, the 'select' event is called before the tab is shown, and the 'show' event after the tab is shown. It works now, thanks!